Curl Error: 61 (BAD_CONTENT_ENCODING) when debugging using developers.facebook.com
I can't figure it out. I want to set my og:url to the same value as my canonical URL -- but when I do, Facebook Share stops working.
Both URL's have the exact same content but are served from a different environment.
My canonical URL
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.filmfix.com/en/8mm-transfer/professional-super-8-film-transfer-/">

When I set the og:url to
<meta property="og:url" content="https://api.filmfix.com/landingpage_super_8_dvd_filmtransfer.asp?l=e&lp_post=2787">

the Facebook Share works (served with header Content-Encoding: gzip).
But when set to
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.filmfix.com/en/8mm-transfer/professional-super-8-film-transfer-/">

Facebook Share is not finding the Open Graph content. The page content is served using header Content-Encoding: br.
I am thinking it has to do with the way I am serving the content.
The canonical URL environment is serving pre-compressed HTML files. These Brotli compressed HTML file have a .br extension.
Note, the server is currently set up to only serve Brotli compressed content. So no backup content for devices that do not support Brotli content.
Maybe my question should have been: "Is Facebook Share not supporting content that is only available as Brotli content?"

I think I might have answered my own question with my last rewrite. I will be looking into serving also g-zip compresses content alongside my Brotli content.

I can now confirm that Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ is not checking (supporting) content if it is only available as Brotli compresses content.
